# Problem in player Rotation in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to rotate game camera using my android device orientation.[Like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRnRDrcUOek)  Using accelerometer input of device this may be done. But I don't know how to do this. I tried lot of methods, but failed. Anybody please help.

I am using unity 5.3 with C#.

Comment: Thanks @smkplus, I already tried this, but its not working. public float speed = 10.0F;
 void Update() {
  Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
  dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
  dir.z = Input.acceleration.x;
  if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
   dir.Normalize();

  dir *= Time.deltaTime;
  transform.Rotate(dir * speed);
 }